# Reproduce streaming vlc on android and iphone

Tags: android, iphone, streaming, video-streaming, vlc

I have a web page that plays rtsp links. I am using vlc embedded plugin to play the streams.

```
    <object classid="clsid:9BE31822-FDAD-461B-AD51-BE1D1C159921" codebase="http://downloads.videolan.org/pub/videolan/vlc/latest/win32/axvlc.cab" width="400" height="300" id="vlc" events="True"> 
        <param name="ShowDisplay" value="True" ></param> 
        <param name="Volume" value="100" />
        <param name="AutoLoop" value="no"></param> 
        <param name="AutoPlay" value="yes"></param> 
        <embed type="application/x-google-vlc-plugin" name="vlcfirefox" autoplay="yes" loop="no" width="400" height="300" target="rtsp://<publicIp>:8554/stream"></embed> 
    </object>


    <script type='text/javascript'>
       window.onload = function(){
         var vlc = document.getElementById('vlc');
         vlc.playlist.playItem( vlc.playlist.add("rtsp://<publicIP>:8554/stream", "live", ":network-caching=150") );
       };
    </script>
```

I have no problem whatching the rtsp on PC across all browsers. But I can't see the stream on android or iphone.

Android browser doesn't recognize the vlc object and on chrome for android I receive the message: "chrome for android doesn't support this plugin".

On iphone I'm having the same problem.

Is there any solution for this? Is it possible to watch a video with the vlc web plugin on android and/or iphone?

Thanks.